# how config fixed/static column in ng2-smart-table?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I've tried all possible Angular plugins for tables. By far the fastest is ng2-smart-table, but the option, that I'm looking for is the pinned/fixed column. Is there an option to have that?

That's not all actually, I would like to have:

fixed/static header AND
fixed/static column.

```
source: LocalDataSource;
  settingsTable = {
    columns: {
      ID: {
        title: 'ID',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      ENCODER:{
        title: 'ENCODER',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      IRD: {
        title: 'IRD',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      NOMBRE_COMPANY:{
        title: 'NOMBRE_COMPANY',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      CHANNEL_ID:{
        title: 'CHANNEL_ID',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      CATEGORIA:{
        title: 'CATEGORIA',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      PROGRAMADOR:{
        title: 'PROGRAMADOR',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
      FORMATO:{
        title: 'FORMATO',
        width: '10%',
        show: true,
      },
    },
    noDataMessage: "No se encontraron resultados.",
    mode: "external",
    actions: false,
    attr: {
      class: 'table table-bordered '
    },
    pager: {
      perPage: 100,
      display: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some angular components have problems. I suggest you that make the statics columns with css

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).